# Having trouble joining information from two tables using timestamps

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables in BigQuery:

- A - Has the exact start and end time of the processes
- B - It has the cost per hour of several products consumed by the processes

I need to calculate an estimate of the cost of each process (table A) using the data in table B. I thought of doing this by summing the cost of all products (table B) included in the time period consumed by the process in table A.

So, here is some fake data for the two tables and the desired output:

**Process metadata (Table A)**

| process_name | timestamp_init | timestamp_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021-04-01 11:15:44.888153 UTC | 2021-04-01 12:25:44.888153 UTC |
| b | 2021-04-01 13:50:17.033498 UTC | 2021-04-01 14:50:17.033498 UTC |
| c | 2008-04-02 20:19:36.983747 UTC | 2008-04-02 20:58:20.983747 UTC |
| d | 2010-04-02 22:06:10.348753 UTC | 2010-04-02 23:08:28.348753 UTC |

**Platform costs (Table B)**

| product | usage_start_time | usage_end_time | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ax | 2021-04-01 11:00:00 UTC | 2021-04-01 12:00:00 UTC | 10 |
| b4 | 2021-04-01 11:00:00 UTC | 2021-04-01 12:00:00 UTC | 9 |
| cf | 2021-04-01 11:00:00 UTC | 2021-04-01 12:00:00 UTC | 25 |
| jw | 2021-04-01 14:00:00 UTC | 2021-04-01 15:00:00 UTC | 125 |
| ki | 2021-04-01 20:00:00 UTC | 2021-04-01 21:00:00 UTC | 180 |
| fr | 2021-04-01 22:00:00 UTC | 2021-04-01 23:00:00 UTC | 250 |

**Desired Results**

| process_name | total_cost |
| --- | --- |
| a | 44 |
| b | 125 |
| c | 180 |
| d | 250 |

I developed the following code:

```sql
SELECT  a.process_name,
        SUM(b.cost) as total_cost

FROM    A a,
        B b

WHERE   b.usage_start_time >= timestamp_trunc(timestamp_add(a.timestamp_init, interval 30 minute), hour)
AND     b.usage_end_time <= timestamp_trunc(timestamp_add(a.timestamp_end, interval 30 minute), hour)

GROUP BY a.process_name
```

Note that I'm rounding the timestamps from table A so it matches the format of table B.

But for some reason I don't know, it is not returning any results. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the 30 minutes is coming from.  The logic for an overlap would be:

```
SELECT  a.process_name,
        SUM(b.cost) as total_cost
FROM A a JOIN
     B b
     ON b.usage_start_time < a.timestamp_end AND
        b.ussage_end_time >= a.timestamp_init
GROUP BY a.process_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it will be very useful. The 30-minute logic aims to round the date correctly. "timestamp_trunc" acts similarly as floor, so to round 14:58 to 15:00 (and not to 14:00), I need to add 30 minutes.

Comment: @DunkelLocust . . . I'm a little unclear why rounding is necessary if you just need to detect an overlap.